# Counting Inversions (Issue with Large Input)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, mergesort

I am currently working on counting inversions exercise using mergesort. The problem I am facing is when I have small or medium sized array the result is perfectly fine however if I use a very large testcase (an array of 100,000 integers) it does not give me correct number of inversions. I have no clue as to why is that happening. Here is my code:

```
static int [] helper;
static long count=0;
static Integer [] arr3;

private static void mergeSortMethod(Integer[] arr3) {
    int head=0;
    int tail=arr3.length-1;
    int mid=tail+((head-tail)/2);

    sort(arr3,head,tail);
}


private static void sort(Integer[] arr3, int low, int high) {

    if (high<=low){
        return;
    }
    int mid=low+ ((high-low)/2);

    sort(arr3,low,mid);
    sort(arr3,mid+1,high);

    merge3CountInvs(arr3,low,mid,high);

}

private static void merge3CountInvs(Integer[] arr3, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int i=low;
    int j=mid+1;
    int k=low;
    //to get size of first half of array
    int nArr1Elems=(mid-low)+1;

    for (int m=low;m<=high;m++){
        helper[m]=arr3[m];

    }

    while(i < mid+1 && j < high+1){// neither array empty
        if( helper[i] < helper[j] ){
            arr3[k++] = helper[i++];

        }

        else if ( helper[j] < helper[i] ){
            arr3[k++] = helper[j++];
            int numOFElements=nArr1Elems-i;
            count=count+(nArr1Elems-i);

        }
    }
    while(i < mid+1){ // arrayB is empty,
        arr3[k++] = helper[i++];
    }

    while(j < high+1){ // arrayA is empty,
        arr3[k++] = helper[j++];
    }

}
```

My solution gives correct answers when not using very large inputs however when I used test case of 100,000 integers that was the number of inversions I got:

From my implementation: -30588581433

Correct answer is: 2407905288

Any ideas? I would appreciate any sort of help. Thank you.

EDIT:
As mentioned in the answers about the integer overflow case that is the point I am having a hard time to understand since variable "count" which causes overflow is initialized as "long" hence there should be no overflow in this case. I can not think of any other variable that would cause integer overflow in my code. Thanks a lot.

UPDATE:

There was no issue related to Integer overflow but thanks for the answers however Reddy's answer did point me into right direction so thanks once again. The only mistake in my algorithm was:

```
int nArr1Elems=(mid-low)+1; 

count=count+(nArr1Elems-i);
```

When it should have been:

```
count=count+(mid-i+1);
```

As we have to subtract from the elements left on the left side of array "after" sorting not initially when the subroutine is called since the index changes after sorting. I am writing my updated code in case if anyone else would end up in a similar issue as mine:

```
static int [] helper;
static long count=0;
static Integer [] arr3;

private static void mergeSortMethod(Integer[] arr3) {
    int head=0;
    int tail=arr3.length-1;
    int mid=tail+((head-tail)/2);

    sort(arr3,head,tail);
}


private static void sort(Integer[] arr3, int low, int high) {

    if (high<=low){
        return;
    }
    int mid=low+ ((high-low)/2);

    sort(arr3,low,mid);
    sort(arr3,mid+1,high);

    merge3CountInvs(arr3,low,mid,high);

}

private static void merge3CountInvs(Integer[] arr3, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int i=low;
    int j=mid+1;
    int k=low;

    for (int m=low;m<=high;m++){
        helper[m]=arr3[m];

    }

    while(i < mid+1 && j < high+1){// neither array empty
        if( helper[i] < helper[j] ){
            arr3[k++] = helper[i++];

        }

        else if ( helper[j] < helper[i] ){
            arr3[k++] = helper[j++];
         //to increment count with total number of elements left in arrayA after sorting
            count=count+(mid-i+1);

        }
    }
    while(i < mid+1){ // arrayB is empty,
        arr3[k++] = helper[i++];
    }

    while(j < high+1){ // arrayA is empty,
        arr3[k++] = helper[j++];
    }

}
```

Comment: "*I would appreciate any **sort** of help.*" Pun intended?

Comment: I can see some mistakes in your algorithm. please check with my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code is working fine for your data and I am getting perfectly right result.
Please compare with it and check what you are doing wrong in the algorithm

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
            int[] dataInv = new int[100000];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataInv.length; i++) {
                dataInv[i] = rand.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println("Inversions: " + numberOfInversions(dataInv));
    }

   private static long numberOfInversions(int[] data) {
        int[] temp = new int[data.length];
        return mergeSort(data, temp, 0, data.length - 1);
    }

    private static long mergeSort(int[] data, int[] temp, int low, int high) {
        long inversions = 0L;
        if (high > low) {

            int mid = (high + low) / 2;

            inversions = mergeSort(data, temp, low, mid);
            inversions += mergeSort(data, temp, mid + 1, high);

            inversions += merge(data, temp, low, mid + 1, high);
        }

        return inversions;
    }

    private static long merge(int[] data, int[] temp, int low, int mid, int high) {
        int i, j, k = 0;
        long invertions = 0L;

        i = low;
        j = mid;
        k = low;

        while (i <= (mid - 1) && j <= high) {
            if (data[i] <= data[j]) {
                temp[k++] = data[i++];
            } else {
                temp[k++] = data[j++];

                invertions += (mid - i);
            }
        }

        while (i <= (mid - 1)) {
            temp[k++] = data[i++];
        }

        while (j <= high) {
            temp[k++] = data[j++];
        }

        for (i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            data[i] = temp[i];
        }

        return invertions;

    }
```

Comment: for one of the input, answer is "Inversions: 2498734398"

So it should be working correct

Comment: The problem in my code was:

    int nArr1Elems=(mid-low)+1;

    count=count+(nArr1Elems-i);

when it should have been:

    count=count+(mid-i+1);

as we have to subtract from the elements left on the left side of array "after" sorting not initially when the method is called. So thanks a lot. That did give me some direction.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to store a number greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` - try using a `long` instead

Comment: That is why I have initialized "count" as long that causes integer overflow however I can not notice any other variable causing overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You are using numbers that do not fit into 32-bit integer and therefore you have an overflow. Use `long` for results smaller than 2^63 or [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for all possible integers which fit in your memory.

Comment: The variable that causes overflow is "count" & as you can see it is initialized as long. I can not see any other variable causing integer overflow. If you do notice such a variable then please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: `long.MAX_VALUE` is  `2^63 - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this: Suppose you call sort() on the subarray where low=99990 and high=99999.  Then mid=99994.  In merge3CountInvs(), what will nArr1Elems be?  What range of values will "i" take on?  What will be added to count in the statement

```
       count=count+(nArr1Elems-i);
```

?